# Recursive website mirroring with filtering

Tags: linux, wget

Trying to fetch a bunch of files from a website without downloading the full content. Here is what I'm trying:

```
wget --no-clobber --convert-links --random-wait -r -p --level 10 -e robots=off -U mozilla -A zip,gdb,gpx http://www.mtb-bg.com
```

Without `-A` option full website is mirrored. Once I add the filter list I got zilch. I guess the problem is full link structure must be created first and then filtered extensions have to be fetched as a second step. Any clue how to do this with minimum amount of code?